# How do I make my ball roll like a ball when my character walks into it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i just want my ball to roll in the direction that it was hit away from the character.

so far ive got this code:

```
public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 2;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float movementHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float movementVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementHorizontal, 0.0f, movementVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you could use [`AddForceAtPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html) and always apply the force at the top point of the ball

Comment: I know it's not the question but you should multiply your speed with Time.fixedDeltaTime or you will get strange behavior in the future. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume you are not having an issue translating the ball.  That looks correct for doing linear force.  In order to get the ball to roll, you need to calculate the torque, or the angular force.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) is some reference material from unity on using torque.

As per their example:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float torque;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float turn = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.AddTorque(transform.up * torque * turn);
    } }
```

Comment: thanks this worked. I also had to untick my ground is trigger and tick use gravity for the ball!